# What is the correct way to add field to database models that are only relevant for some of them?

Tags: database, database-design

Edit: To clarify, each of these models are mapped to a database table.

Consider the following scenario. I have a model detailing a payment:

```
class Payment:
  type = ChoiceField(['CASH', 'CREDIT_CARD'])
  amount = MoneyField()
```

One day, the company would like to also store the last four digits of the credit card used, if paying with credit card. Now I have several options:

Option 1: add an "optional" field to Payment that only gets filled if type is CREDIT_CARD:

```
class Payment:
  ...
  credit_card_no = StringField(required=False)
```

Option 2: create another class that points to Payment if it's a Credit Card payment:

```
class CreditCardNumber:
  credit_card_no = StringField()
  payment = OneToOneRelation(Payment)
```

But I am unsure which option is preferrable. What is the usual / preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it really depends on which language platform you are on. I will give you an answer for a Javascript app.

Even if in JS you can add custom properties to any instance completely freely my opinion is that you should **keep original properties and optional properties under control** with something like this (pseudo code):

```
class Payment:
  type = ...
  amount = ...
  optional_fields = {}

  setField(name, val) ->
    this.optional_fields[name] = val

  getField(name) ->
    return this.optional_fields[name]
```

This approach let your class to be a well defined entity in your system with **no random amount of properties** but you are still able to extend it at your will to host optional informations.

If you go with the sub-class approach you may find yourself in defining a high number of sub-classes... like 'PaymentWithCreditCard', 'PaymentWithPayPalAccount', etc... what if you discover that you need to combine different sub-classes? you can easily loose control of it!

Comment: I forgot to clarify, but for my purpose, these models are stored in a database (so, it is very hard to use your approach, since it is not type-enforced). Also, none of the options I gave were subclasses, right? The second is a "detail table" approach.

Comment: I would go with the optional fields map in which each field is represented by it's own typed class in which you can encapsulate the knowledge of "how/where to persist".

Comment: And the reasoning is?

Comment: So the consumers of the Payment class can access any information by name but internally you can store those informations with the one-to-one relation you wrote. Also this solution is open to receive more optional informations without affecting the class structure.

Comment: But this solution will incur an additional JOIN or table search for every such query. In addition, if an instance of the Payment object were to get modified, then we have to manually check whether the optional field is still consistent (and remove if it is not). I'm not convinced that this is better than the simple "append a field that can be null" option. (the first option also have cons, mainly since it... sounds wrong philosophically).

Comment: mmm you asked for a code suggestion, on a db level I agree that if you know you have a limited amount of optional fields (like one field) than it's expensive to handle it in a related table. But the data model representation in your code doesn't have to match your persistency strategy at all, with the optional fields map you are always able to refactor your persistency strategy to adapt to future needs and you software will not change. (say you move from relational to big data by instance...)

Comment: It's a "database model" code (i.e., instead of directly accessing the db, I assume a high level db models manager). Semi-adapted from Django's models.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68551/discussion-between-marcopeg-and-irvan).